# Writing drivers for ActiveRecord(Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

how to write own database drivers for Rails 3? I mean to write for example MongoDB driver, so it can be used without any changes to models and using different gems like MongoID and MongoMapper. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a driver is no easy undertaking, but generally the best practice is to look at a few other drivers, strip them down to the essentials, and build back up by filling in the gaps.

ActiveRecord comes with Postgres, MySQL, SQLite3 and SQLite adapters, so you could write your own using these as examples. These are in `lib/active_record/connection_adapters` and are all based on the generic AbstractAdapter.

You may have trouble trying to write a wrapper for a non-SQL database where a lot of assumptions are made by ActiveRecord about what kind of facilities the underlying storage mechanism has.

Comment: Could you please provide me a link to that directory in Rails 3 GitHub repo(https://github.com/rails/rails)? Very thankful to you!

Comment: It's in the ActiveRecord gem itself. Have a look in your installed gems folder, or in [activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/) on github.